# C# Use generic that references itself in concrete class declaration

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Coming from Java, I think I should be able to do something like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

interface ICoord<T> where T : ICoord<T>
{
    ICollection<T> GetNeighbors();
}


class SquareCoord : ICoord<SquareCoord>
{
    public ICollection<SquareCoord> GetNeighbors() {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}


interface IGrid<T> where T : ICoord<T>
{
    List<T> GetGrid();
}


// This works no problem (everything is concretely defined)
class SquareGrid : IGrid<SquareCoord>
{
    public List<SquareCoord> GetGrid() {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}


class Grid : IGrid<ICoord>
{
    public List<ICoord> GetGrid() 
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

where the last class `Grid` should be able to operate and return a List of any (concrete implementation of) `ICoord`.

I have a small working example in Java. If I could get the equivalent (if possible) in C#, that would give me enough to go on.

```
public class Example {
    private interface Index<T extends Index> {
        List<T> GetNeighbors();
    }

    private static class SquareIndex implements Index<SquareIndex> {
        public List<SquareIndex> GetNeighbors(){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    private interface Grid<T extends Index> {
        List<T> GetGrid();
    }

    // Java does not require a type parameter to implement "Grid"
    private static class MyGrid implements Grid {
        // Java allows me to satisfy the requirements for implementing "Grid"
        // without having a concrete type defined in the method declaration.
        public List<? extends Index> GetGrid() {
            final List<SquareIndex> result = new ArrayList<>();
            result.add(new SquareIndex());
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyGrid g = new MyGrid();
        g.GetGrid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My excellent girlfriend just figured it out:

```
class MyGrid<T> : IGrid<T> where T : ICoord<T>
{
    public List<T> GetGrid() {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```